# How to prevent stopwatch timer reset after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript stopwatch that begins with page onload. I am trying to keep the counter from resetting back to zero after page refresh. I believe I can use sessionStorage or localStorage. I'm just not sure how to implement it with the code I already have. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
       <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>



    <script type="text/javascript">
var timeBegan = null
    , timeStopped = null
    , stoppedDuration = 0
    , started = null;

function start() {
    if (timeBegan === null) {
        timeBegan = new Date();
    }

    if (timeStopped !== null) {
        stoppedDuration += (new Date() - timeStopped);
    }
    console.log(stoppedDuration);

    started = setInterval(clockRunning, 10);    
}

function stop() {
    timeStopped = new Date();
    clearInterval(started);
}
        function reset() {
    clearInterval(started);
    stoppedDuration = 0;
    timeBegan = null;
    timeStopped = null;
    document.getElementById("display-area").innerHTML = "00:00:00.000";
}

function clockRunning(){
    var currentTime = new Date()
        , timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime - timeBegan - stoppedDuration)
        , hour = timeElapsed.getUTCHours()
        , min = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes()
        , sec = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds()
        , ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds();

    document.getElementById("display-area").innerHTML = 
        (hour > 9 ? hour : "0" + hour) + ":" + 
        (min > 9 ? min : "0" + min) + ":" + 
        (sec > 9 ? sec : "0" + sec) + "." + 
        (ms > 99 ? ms : ms > 9 ? "0" + ms : "00" + ms);
};
    </script>



</head>



<body onload="start();">
<div>
            <textarea id="display-area" style="font-size: 18px; color:chartreuse; height:22px; background-color: black; padding-left:16px; padding-right: 12px;  width:133px; border: groove; border-width: 4px; border-color: goldenrod; border-radius: 3px; resize:none; overflow:hidden">00:00:00.000</textarea>
        </div><input type="button" form="time" onclick="stop();" value="stop"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Each time the stopwatch starts, stops, or "ticks", store its current value in `localStorage`, and also store a stopped/running status flag. Then on page load you can check the stored details and set/start the stopwatch as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rd2xafnr/4/). It does just wat you want, storing start time in localStorage and retrieving it on every load.

```
function start() {
  startTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('startTime') || Date.now());
  localStorage.setItem('startTime', startTime);
  timer = setInterval(clockTick, 100);
}
```

Comment: Works great! I see and understand it now. Appreciate you spreading the knowledge!

Comment: @J.Parker, can you then set this question as solved?